# How to return same type as the argument

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, I need to wrap the [`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) built-in function with another function.

The problem is I need to implement this behaviour:

> **Return Types**
>
> The return data type is the data type of the date argument[...]

For example, if I pass in a `datetime` as argument, `DATEADD` returns a `datetime`. If I pass in a `date`, `DATEADD` returns a `date`.

The following example always returns `datetime`...

```
create function add_months(@dt date, @interval int) 
   returns datetime
as
begin
   return DATEADD(month, @interval, @dt)
end
```

How can I implement this in SQL Server?

***(edit)***

**Context**

I'm performing a database migration from informix to SQL Server. The database part is not the issue here, the code is. We have hundreds of programs that must be changed because of the SQL queries embedded in them. This is the main reason I'm trying to avoid to use `DATEADD(MONTH, 1, foo)`. This **automatic** transformation, while simple in most cases, can be quite difficult in some cases. With a udf I could just replace the name of the informix function and not go into a deeper refactoring.

Comment: You can't. There are differences between what you can achieve in TSQL (and even in CLR), and what the SQL Server programmers can do, when they have full reign within the product.

Comment: At the very least, this should teach you not to embed SQL queries in your applications, or barring that, understand the complexity of changing database platforms when you have done so.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, these are not my queries, applications or databases nor did I have something to do with the code. I'm just doing the migration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overloaded functions aren't possible. I'm trying to think of a way to shoehorn `SQL_VARIANT` into this but all of the options I can think of lead to unnecessarily disgusting complications. I would make a function that accepts and returns date, and a function that accepts and returns datetime, and call the appropriate one. The ones with lower precision can call the ones with higher so you don't have to replicate code, e.g.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.add_months_to_datetime
(@dt DATETIME, @interval INT)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN DATEADD(MONTH, @interval, @dt);
END
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.add_months_to_date
(@dt DATE, @interval INT)
RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN dbo.add_months_to_datetime(@dt, @interval);
END
GO
```

Alternatively, just always use the highest precision (1st function), and worry about whether it's a date or datetime when you present the data. You can do this with an inline convert or wrapping it in another function appropriately.

**EDIT**

Or better yet, just replace all calls to this function of questionable value with proper inline dateadd calls.

```
dbo.add_months(foo, 1)
```

Becomes:

```
DATEADD(MONTH, 1, foo)
```

While it's not as automatic as you might like, in addition to maintaining your requirement that the output type remains the same as the input, this will also probably improve performance of some queries, depending on where these are used within the query.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I really really need this behavior because I'm doing an automatic migration from informix to SQL Server and if I'm going to have 2 functions I will need to determine the type of the arguments in each call, otherwise it is just a find/replace.

Comment: Just because you "really really need" it does not magically make SQL Server capable of doing it, sorry.

Comment: @brunoconde Perhaps starting with some of those goals surrounding the migration and how you are doing it would get you answers more likely to help your migration.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I will consider your question correct because this is not possible in SQL Server. However, built-in functions like DATEADD do this. I think it's reasonable to expect I could also do this but, as you say, only with magic. I edited the question to add some context that explains why I didn't want to use DATEADD(MONTH, 1, foo).

Comment: @CadeRoux, added some background context to the question about the migration.

Comment: @brunoconde *you* can't write a built-in function, which was the essence of Damien's comment. The SQL Server dev team has access to a wide variety of magic that you, as a mere SQL Server user, do not.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the poor performance of scalar functions in SQL Server, I would just generally avoid this or use Aaron's technique.

However, you can use an abomination like this if you have to have that syntax:

```
create function dbo.add_months(@dt sql_variant, @interval int) 
   returns sql_variant
as
begin
   IF SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@dt, 'BaseType') = 'datetime'
       return DATEADD(month, @interval, CAST(@dt AS DATETIME))
   ELSE IF SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@dt, 'BaseType') = 'date'
       return DATEADD(month, @interval, CAST(@dt AS DATE))
   RETURN null
end

DECLARE @d DATE = '20120705';
DECLARE @dt DATETIME = '20120705 12:30:30';

SELECT dbo.add_months(@d, 1), dbo.add_months(@dt, 1);
```

You can see in this SQLFiddle that there are now issues getting the data out from the sql_variant into something useful: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f95ba/4

Comment: I don't get `DATE` as the type in the output here though, I get `DATETIME` in both cases (well, time is included in the formatted string). And if I try to perform date/time operations on the output in either case, I get `Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to datetime is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.` I can only assume the same will happen if you try to use the output in a join or where clause. Which means you can't just use the function directly, you need to wrap the output in `CONVERT` anyway, so using `SQL_VARIANT` hasn't gained you anything.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Indeed, SQLFiddle is fixed and I can SELECT but not INSERT.  I'm assuming you would also have similar issues in client-side extraction of column values.  I'll leave this answer as an approach to avoid.